# openshift symfony install third party libraries

Tags: php, symfony, openshift

I'm trying to add FosUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle to my symfony project in openshift. In localhost, to add those libraries, I'd to edit composer.json and update the composer.phar. Now I don't know how to update the composer.phar on openshift.

**My way(step-by-step):**

1. Create a symfony app from openshift
2. clone the project to my localhost
3. edit the composer.json and push it again to openshift

after that, what should I do to update the composer? Or is there another way to add those libraries to the symfony project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to setup an action_hook to run the composer command on the openshift server after you do a git push, maybe in the deploy action_hook.  Another idea would be to install the libraries locally using composer and then add them into git and push all of it up to the server with a git push and let it all be deployed together.  As far as I know composer is not installed on the server, so you may need to install it into your app-root/data directory and call it from there with your deploy hook.

Here is a blog article about using composer with OpenShift: http://stanlemon.net/2013/03/22/composer-on-openshift/ that might help answer your question